# Enabling and Disabling a S3 Replication Rule through api/cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have set up a replication rule on my S3 bucket to populate a preprod bucket for testing purposes. This means I will want to be able to turn the replication on and off easily, and likely dump and refresh the replication bucket as necessary. I'm creating a script for this but am having a hard time finding a way to easily turn the replication rule on and off outside of using the AWS Console.

Is there an option beyond put-bucket-replication? That works but is basically restating the whole replication config each time, instead of just enabling or disabling the existing one.

Comment: S3 replication is controlled by a configuration file with one or more rules. It's not an on/off kind of thing afaik. You could create two JSON files, representing the two replication configuration states you want, and then invoke put-bucket-replication with the relevant file.

Comment: Yeah, that is the solution I am seeing, but it seemed a little contrived so i wanted to check there wasn't something like aws s3 config-bucket-replication --bucket bucketname --rule rulename --enable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the only solution is to pass different put-bucket-replications with the Status as disabled or enabled. Example of disabled below using python and boto3:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

##Enable
client.put_bucket_replication(Bucket='yoursourcebucketname', ReplicationConfiguration={
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::999999999:role/service-role/yourrolename",
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Status": "Disabled",
            "Priority": 1,
            "DeleteMarkerReplication": { "Status": "Disabled" },
            "Filter" : { "Prefix": ""},
            "Destination": {
                "Bucket": "arn:aws:s3:::yourlandingbucket",
                "Account": "838382828"
            }
        }
    ]
}
)
```

Comment: I've been fuffing about this configuration for an hour.. 
Thank you for posting