# Python Boto3 PutBucketReplication operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I'm trying to update the bucket's replication rule using python boto3. But I keep getting the error: `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the PutBucketReplication operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema`

I'm following the documentation here to do this: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_replication

Here is my function that's getting run. Can anyone see what's wrong with the xml that I'm passing?

```
def apply_bucket_replication_rule(client):
    response = client.put_bucket_replication(
        Bucket= 'my-bucket',
            'Role': 'arn:aws:iam::0123456:role/replicate_s3_buckets',
            'Rules': [
                {
                    'Status': 'Enabled',
                    'Destination': {
                        'Bucket': 'arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-backup',
                        'Account': '111222333'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
    )
    print (response)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57778885/9931092

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem, following the answer of (stackoverflow.com/a/57778885/9931092) worked for me, that's my example of working code:

```
def apply_bucket_replication_rule(client):
response = client.put_bucket_replication(
    Bucket='mybucket',
    ReplicationConfiguration={
        'Role': 'arn:aws:iam::0123456:role/replicate_s3_buckets',
        'Rules': [
            {
                "Status": "Disabled",
                "Priority": 1,
                "DeleteMarkerReplication": {"Status": "Disabled"},
                "Filter": {"Prefix": ""},
                "Destination": {
                    "Bucket": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-backup",
                    "Account": "111222333"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
print(response)
```

Comment: For me, omitting the _Filter_ property in the rule produced this schema validation error. A bit unintuitive because it can be empty as stated in the answer.