# XML provided is not well formed for boto script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am working on a boto script that will enable S3 bucket cross region replication, I have followed this "https://stackoverflow.com/a/57778885/9931092" answer for my script, the script seems to work fine for me but it does not have `ExistingObjectReplication` as part of the code and while adding that does not make the code run.
This is my boto script:

```
import boto3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

response = s3_client.put_bucket_versioning(
    Bucket='cross-test-6',
    VersioningConfiguration={
        'Status': 'Enabled'
    },
)

response = s3_client.put_bucket_versioning(
    Bucket='cross-test-7',
    VersioningConfiguration={
        'Status': 'Enabled'
    },
)



##Enable
s3_client.put_bucket_replication(Bucket='cross-test-6', 
ReplicationConfiguration={
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::196687784845:role/test",
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "Priority": 1, 
            "DeleteMarkerReplication": { "Status": "Disabled" },
            "ExistingObjectReplication": { "Status": "Enabled" },
            "Filter" : { "Prefix": ""},            
            "Destination": {
                "Bucket": "arn:aws:s3:::cross-test-7",
                "Account": "196687784845"
            },           
        }
    ]
}
)
```

This is the Traceback I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pranay/Desktop/Amit/main-2.py", line 21, in <module>
    s3_client.put_bucket_replication(Bucket='cross-test-6', 
  File "/home/pranay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 337, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/pranay/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 656, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the PutBucketReplication operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
```

My suspicion is that the official documentation has `'ExistingObjectReplication'` rather than  `"ExistingObjectReplication"`, although I have tried that as well and got the same error.

Comment: What version of boto3 are you using? Have you tried the latest version?

Comment: I just updated the boto3 version and tried again and got the same error.